# extract font character image from ttf file

Tags: image, fonts, truetype

Does anyone knows how to extract the characters image from a font(ttf) file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TTF is a vector format, so there are no characters shapes, really. Load the font, select it into a device context (a memory one), render a character, grab a bitmap.

Relevant APIs: AddFontResource, CreateFont, CreateDC, CreateBitmap, SelectObject, TextOut (or DrawText).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GetGlyphOutline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144891(VS.85).aspx) with `GGO_BEZIER` to get the shape of a single character.

Comment: do you know the same function in C#?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness I'd like to add a GUI and Python way to this pretty old thread.

If the goal is to extract images (as e.g. png) from a .ttf file I found two pretty straight forward ways which both involve the open-source program **fontforge** ([Link to their website](https://fontforge.org/en-US/)):

- **GUI Way** (Suitable for extracting a handful of characters): Open the .ttf file in fontforge click on the character you want to export. Then: file -> export -> format:png
- **CLI / Python Way** (Suitable for automation): FontForge has a cli api for python 2.7 which allows to automate the extraction of the images. Refer to [this superuser thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1337567/how-do-i-convert-a-ttf-into-individual-png-character-images) for a complete script.

Link 1: https://fontforge.org/en-US/
Link 2: https://superuser.com/questions/1337567/how-do-i-convert-a-ttf-into-individual-png-character-images